# Using new Websocket(<uri>) causes the websocket to hang on connecting even after handshake is received

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, handshake

I have a very very irritating bug in my code that just doesn't seem to show itself.

The situation:
I am using 3 different websockets to connect to 3 different websocketservers through localhost. So client A connects to server A and so on... The client cycles through the connections to make and tries each one in order. If it fails or succeeds, it goes to the next one. If the connection failed, the connection to make it placed at the back of the queue. I switch to the next one in the list using both the onopen and onclose function.

The problem:
I am using the following code snippet to start a connection from the client:

```
this.ws = new WebSocket(this.url);
this.ws.parent = this;
this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage;
this.ws.onerror = this.onError;
this.ws.onclose = this.onClose;
```

The this object is a wrapper object in this case. The functions supplied are all found and correct.

What happens is, the connection is created with the server. The server sends a very basic handshake reply. I wiresharked the situation and am 100% sure the handshake is received by the client (it is ACK'ed by the TCP connection). However, the onopen function is not called and the websocket seems to stay in the connecting state. If I wait really long, I can get a timeout on the handshake. If I close the server, I get an error the connection has reset.

This problem is random. Sometimes when you start the client, it will work and all 3 connections are made succesfully. Sometimes, it fails at the first attempt to connect to the first server. Sometimes the first connection is successfull and the second fails and so on.

The problem shows itself under Windows with Opera, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

I also tried this without cycling through a list of connections to make but just let each socket retry its connection on its own onclose. Doesn't fix anything either.

Can someone please end my suffering? The last thing I can think of, is that each javascript engine is just broken which, of course, is very unlikely.

One situation which I used to, more or less, force the problem most of the time (doesn't work everytime) is to start the server and than open the page in the client. This causes the connection on A and B to fail and C to succeed on its first try but than it hangs (most of the times).

Is it possible that the bug is caused by the fact that another websocket has just failed and the next one hangs because of some reason of the previous failed one?

Code on a failed close to try reconnect later:

```
SOCKETSTOCONNECT.addToConnect(object.parent);
SOCKETSTOCONNECT.tryToConnectNext();
```

Code on a succesfull open to try and connect next:

```
SOCKETSTOCONNECT.tryToConnectNext();
```

Code to know which to connect to still (addconnect takes the wrapper websocket object):

```
function SocketsToConnect() {
    this.toConnect = [];

    this.addToConnect = function(websocket) {
        this.toConnect.push(websocket);
    }

    this.tryToConnectNext = function() {
        for(var i =0; i < this.toConnect.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.toConnect[i]);
        }

        var next = this.toConnect.shift();

        if(next) {
            next.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Global variable:

```
var SOCKETSTOCONNECT = new SocketsToConnect();
```

Wrapper websocket object:

```
function Websocket(name, ipaddress, port, onOpen, onMessage, onError, onClose) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ipaddress = ipaddress;
    this.port = port;
    this.url = "ws://"+ipaddress+":"+port+"/";
    this.connected = false;
    this.onOpen = onOpen;
    this.onMessage = onMessage;
    this.onError = onError;
    this.onClose = onClose;

    this.connect = function() {
                                this.ws = new WebSocket(this.url);
                                this.ws.parent = this;
                                this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
                                this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage;
                                this.ws.onerror = this.onError;
                                this.ws.onclose = this.onClose;    
    }

    this.sendMessage = function (message) {
                           console.log("Sending over ws[" + this.name + "]: " + message);
                           this.ws.send(message);
                       };

    this.sendJSONObject = function (jsonObject) {
                            this.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
                          };

    this.close = function() {
                    console.log("Closing websocket[" + this.name + "]");
                    this.ws.close();
                 };
}
```

EDIT: The websocket handshake I wiresharked:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9163
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Sec-WebSocket-Key: U0WPFXITD+tQAljGSYxeyw==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits


HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: fwqYZzxhRTDFdWMwlHEA5d52JIM=\r\n
\r\n
```

EDIT2:
I found a post on SuperUsers with someone who has the same symptoms but a different cause. https://superuser.com/questions/765076/websocket-handshake-response-not-forwarded-from-tcp-to-client
I checked the SHA1 accept value and it checks out.

EDIT3:
I had a look at the calls using the Chrome developertools. It is kinda weird and it may be because I do not understand completely what is happening. When I have a look at the timeline, I can see the function calls in order. Everytime the line `new WebSocket(this.url);` is called, Chrome will, on a successfull connection do the steps [Destroy WebSocket, Send WebSocket Handshake, Receive WebSocket Handsake]. When it stalls on the connecting state, Chrome only shows the step [Destroy WebSocket] and it seems the "Send WebSocket Handshake" event gets lost. It sounds plausible as that would indeed cause the underlying code to send the handshake request, but never try to read the response. This also seems to show it actually might be a javascript bug.

Could someone please show their thoughts?

EDIT 5:
Here is a picture of the timeline in Google Chrome what I talked about in "EDIT 4". Line 38 is the `new WebSocket(this.url);` line and the order in which the connections happen is canvas.js, keyboard.js and than mouse.js(never comes this far). Canvas.js succeeds and keyboard.js stalls in the connecting state. This screenshot is while keyboard.js hangs.
http://i61.tinypic.com/6j3n9d.png

Comment: Similar issue. I have drilled down the likely cause; It appears to be a bug with the automatic connection retry code, which appears to be global (across all tabs). Only fix is to restart Chrome.

If you attempt to connect to a server which is offline, Chrome will try to connect to it a few times. In some cases (I haven't identified which exactly), the code which is attempting to retry the connection in-fact prevents further connections. Only after keeping the server offline and letting the automatic retry time-out (~3-4 retries) will connections then be allowed to resume normally.